# Have a thread constantly run in background python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a function to check for sniffing tools I want to constantly run in the background of my python script:

```
def check():
    unwanted_programmes = []  # to be added to
    for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']):
        for item in unwanted_programmes:
            if item in str(p.info['name']).lower():
                webhook_hackers(str(p.info['name']))  # send the programme to a webhook which is in another function
                sys.exit()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I want this to run right from the start and then the rest of the script

I have written code like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    check = threading.Thread(target=get_hackers())
    check.start()
    check.join()
    threading.Thread(target=startup).start()

# startup function just does some prints and inputs before running other functions
```

However, this code only runs `check` once and then `startup` but I want `check` to run and then keep running in the background. Meanwhile, `startup` to run just once, how would I do this?

Comment: Why not run the check in the main thread, in a while loop, and startup in the background thread?

Answer (score 0):

Your `check` function does what you want it to, but it only does it once, and that's the behavior that you're seeing; the thread finishes running the function and then cleanly exits. If you place everything in the function inside of a `while(True):` block at the top of the function then the function will loop infinitely and the thread will never exit, which sounds like it's what you want.